# Pyttsx for Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx

I have been looking for several days for a version of pyttsx that works with Python 3 (3.4.2 specifically). I am yet to find a version that works. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: I understand that it's been quite difficult to find an answer for this question... In the other hand, [questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, tools are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in SO.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a patched version :
https://github.com/AMairesse/pyttsx

(pull request for master is in progress)

Answer (score 0):

For python3 you can try this too...
pip3 install https://codeload.github.com/jpercent/pyttsx/zip/master